# ¿Se le puede agregar una scrollbar vertical a este widget?

Tags: python, tkinter

Quiero un `widget` que al presionar los botones me despliegue un menú con una barra `scrollbar` que me muestre máximo 10 o 15 opciones y el resto se tenga que desplazar con la `scrollbar` para poder verlo.

¿Es posible hacerlo con el `widget Menubutton` o hay algún otro `widget` que permita hacer esto?.

Mi idea es un `widget` que me permita seleccionar una fecha de nacimiento con este estilo.

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

root.resizable(False,False)
root.title("Registrarse")
root.geometry("+450+100")
Frame= tk.Frame(root,width=350,height=450,bg="#FAFAFA")
Frame.pack()

Año = tk.Menubutton(Frame,text="Año",bg="#FAFAFA",fg="#212121",font=("Arial",18),direction="above")
Año.place(x=240,y=290)
Mes = tk.Menubutton(Frame,text="Mes",bg="#FAFAFA",fg="#212121",font=("Arial",18),direction="above")
Mes.place(x=160,y=290)
Dia = tk.Menubutton(Frame,text="Dia",bg="#FAFAFA",fg="#212121",font=("Arial",18),direction="above")
Dia.place(x=80,y=290)
AñoMenu = tk.Menu ( Año, tearoff = 0 )
Año.config(menu=AñoMenu)
MesMenu = tk.Menu ( Mes, tearoff = 0 )
Mes.config(menu=MesMenu)
DiaMenu = tk.Menu ( Dia, tearoff = 0 )
Dia.config(menu=DiaMenu)
FechaDias=tk.IntVar()
def Dias(A):
    global FechaDias
    FechaDias = A
    Dia.config(text=FechaDias,width=3)

DiaMenu.add_command(label="1",command=lambda:Dias(1))
DiaMenu.add_command(label="2",command=lambda:Dias(2))
DiaMenu.add_command(label="3",command=lambda:Dias(3))
DiaMenu.add_command(label="4",command=lambda:Dias(4))
DiaMenu.add_command(label="5",command=lambda:Dias(5))
DiaMenu.add_command(label="6",command=lambda:Dias(6))
DiaMenu.add_command(label="7",command=lambda:Dias(7))
DiaMenu.add_command(label="8",command=lambda:Dias(8))
DiaMenu.add_command(label="9",command=lambda:Dias(9))
DiaMenu.add_command(label="10",command=lambda:Dias(10))
DiaMenu.add_command(label="11",command=lambda:Dias(11))
DiaMenu.add_command(label="12",command=lambda:Dias(12))
DiaMenu.add_command(label="13",command=lambda:Dias(13))
DiaMenu.add_command(label="14",command=lambda:Dias(14))
DiaMenu.add_command(label="15",command=lambda:Dias(15))
DiaMenu.add_command(label="16",command=lambda:Dias(16))
DiaMenu.add_command(label="17",command=lambda:Dias(17))
DiaMenu.add_command(label="18",command=lambda:Dias(18))
DiaMenu.add_command(label="19",command=lambda:Dias(19))
DiaMenu.add_command(label="20",command=lambda:Dias(20))
DiaMenu.add_command(label="21",command=lambda:Dias(21))
DiaMenu.add_command(label="22",command=lambda:Dias(22))
DiaMenu.add_command(label="23",command=lambda:Dias(23))
DiaMenu.add_command(label="24",command=lambda:Dias(24))
DiaMenu.add_command(label="25",command=lambda:Dias(25))
DiaMenu.add_command(label="26",command=lambda:Dias(26))
DiaMenu.add_command(label="27",command=lambda:Dias(27))
DiaMenu.add_command(label="28",command=lambda:Dias(28))
DiaMenu.add_command(label="29",command=lambda:Dias(29))
DiaMenu.add_command(label="30",command=lambda:Dias(30))
DiaMenu.add_command(label="31",command=lambda:Dias(31))
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hola Franco, no puedes añadir una barra de scroll por desgracia a un Menu. ¿No te valdría un ComboBox?

Comment: uff, para lo que estás intentando hacer te vendría mejor pyside2.

Comment: Hola, gracias un ComboBox era lo que necesitaba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ni `Menu`, `MenuButton` o `OptionMenu` permiten agregar una barra de Scroll para limitar la altura de los mismos. Se podría de ser necesario implementar un widget propio que emule a un menu, pero requiere su trabajo.

La opción más directa que tenemos en este caso es usar `ttk.ComboBox`, el cual integra por defecto una barra de desplazamiento vertical, además de permitir limitar el número de items a mostrar de forma trivial mediante el argumento `height`.

Dejo un ejemplo reproducible, además se usa `calendar` para obtener los nombres de los meses y ajustar automáticamente el rango de los días en función del mes y año (28, 29, 30,o 31):

```
import calendar
import locale
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

# modificar locale de ser necesario
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'es_ES.UTF8')

def fecha_modificada(event):
    """Se llama cuando se mdifica a fecha"""
    print(f"{dia.get()}/{mes.get()}/{año.get()}")

def _actualizar_dias(event):
    dias = calendar.monthrange(int(año.get()), mes.current() + 1)
    dia['values'] = list(range(1, dias[1] + 1))
    fecha_modificada(event)


root = tk.Tk()

fecha_por_defecto = (2019, 8, 7)
años = list(range(1990, 2020))
meses = calendar.month_name[1:]
dias = list(range(1, calendar.monthrange(*fecha_por_defecto[:2])[1] + 1))

año = ttk.Combobox(root, font=("Arial",18), state="readonly", height=5, values=años)
año.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, padx=10)
mes = ttk.Combobox(root, font=("Arial",18), state="readonly", height=5, values=meses)
mes.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, padx=5)
dia = ttk.Combobox(root, font=("Arial",18), state="readonly", height=5, values=dias)
dia.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, padx=10)

año.current(0)
mes.current(0)
dia.current(0)

año.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", _actualizar_dias)
mes.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", _actualizar_dias)
dia.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", fecha_modificada)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]